# ¿Como recuperar datos de un virtual box?

Tags: virtualbox

He tenido un inconveniente bastante grave con el virtualbox. La cuestión es que lo estaba usando para hacer un proyecto y se cortó la luz.

He podido recuperar parte de los datos gracias a una snapshot que había hecho, pero los datos son de hace un mes (literalmente he perdido más de la mitad de los proyectos que había hecho en la materia). ¿Alguien sabe como puedo recuperar todo lo que tenía en mi virtual box? Estoy desesperado, ya que tengo que entregar en breve y necesito los proyectos :(

Comment: Puede adjuntar (attach) el archivo que es el VM problematico a otro VM y utilizar cualquiere juegos (fsck, chkdsk, etc) que tiene para recuperar datos de discos.

Comment: Crea otra  maquina  virtual  o perfil del mismo tipo del que tenías  pero solo  con lo  esencial.  Levantas esta VM y montas como disco adicional  el archivo  .vdi de tu  VM anterior. Algo  podrás recuperar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero yo haría una snapshot ahora, para que cualquier investigación posterior no arruine más el disco duro virtual.

Y luego intentaría pasar alguna herramienta para diagnóstico de disco, tipo chkdsk o equivalente para linux. Quizá eso repare y recupere sectores de disco que se hayan perdido.

Si lo anterior no funciona, a mí me ayudó en un caso similar esta herramienta: [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_ES). La pena es que habría que instalarlo en el ordenador virtual y eso puede sobreescribir los ficheros del proyecto.

Comment: ¿y si monta el disco de virtual box y después usa PhotoRec desde su pc?  Haciendo algo así `mount (ip de vbox):/path/de/vbox /mount/path` y ejecuta PhotoRec en /mount/path de su pc.

Comment: No creo que funcionara, ya que no es un acceso fisico al disco, sino a traves de protocolo cifs. Eso no leeria los sectores erróneos.